# On Debian 11, how to change from xfce4 to GNOME desktop

Tags: debian, vnc, gnome, debian-bullseye

I installed xfce4 with lightdm on my Debian server (EC2) for users to connect over vnc, so I could run Proton and Windows games. I've since discovered that Flatpak, AppImage, Lutris and Proton greatly prefer GNOME desktop and the plugins for them. SO I'd like to switch to GNOME at this point. I understand the GNOME is more complex.

1. I'm not sure if uninstalling xfce and lightdm are required to succeed, or
2. if I can install GNOME GDM3 and GNOME desktop without concern.
3. Also, how to switch users over to GNOME? Is it just a difference in the .vnc/xstartup file?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to uninstall xfce for gnome you can install it directly with gdm3.
Command to apply :

- sudo apt install gnome-session gdm3
- sudo reboot

After reboot on the user connection interface gdm, you have to choose gnome via the panel up of your screen on the right side.
and that's it.